# Meter shows hot but my outlets in my living room not working

Tags: electrical, wiring

Everything on the breaker works but my living room outlets, and my meter shows 110 volts. Everything else on the same breaker works fine.

Comment: What type of meter, and how are you taking the measurement?

Comment: It's an hyper tough meter and it's got elec, battery and we got it set on 250 my husband has worked on elec for years but this has him stomped

Comment: Sorry, what I'm asking is... When measuring the voltage, what are you measuring between (hot -> neutral, hot -> ground, etc)?

Comment: He's done both I think but I know he done hot to he third hole which is neutral I think

Comment: The reason I ask, is because if he's measuring hot to ground. He would get 120 volts, even if the neutral was broken.  However, the broken neutral would cause devices not to work.

Comment: would you mind posting the solution as an answer. It could help future users.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a change in behavior? You need to follow the path of this circuit to see where it loses power. Turn off the breaker and pull out the last fixture that has power and the first that doesn't. It might be something as simple as a receptacle that was wired with push-in connector that lost contact. I would pull any push-in (aka "backstabbed") receptacle connectors and wire to the screws instead.

Comment: He already did that too what happened is turn tv on this morning and and then all living room outlets quit working then

Comment: With this kind of failure it is the last working outlet or the first non working outlet, it could be a bad connection on the hot or neutral your meter will measure the voltage where no real current will flow, turn on a big load and the circuit opens (very common with back stabs) also a nicked wire during install could have broken) I have found both but 98% of these type of failures in my experiance have been from back stabs, the push in connectors.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure against a known good source of power that the meter is working properly.  Then go back too the living room outlets and check both the above and below receptacle. Often times these type of receptacles are wired in what is called half hot configuration.  Half of the receptacle is full time hot, the other half is switched. The switched half was for floor or table lamps.  If you find half the duplex hot look for a near-by wall switch seemingly unused.  See if that doesn't turn on the other half of these receptacles?  P.

Comment: Done did all that and the meter is brand new and we checked it too with one working still no elec I in outlets in living room

Comment: And we changed the switch and the outlet to it too

Comment: And all is showing hot but not working